# AngularJS service passing data to a controller

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I'm trying to access data from the client side using Loopback and the AngularJS SDK (I think my issue is more to do with my, as yet, not great Angular skills). I am trying to pass the with an AngularJS controller which calls a service as show below.  This does actually work and the data is shown on my web page with {{theSuppliers}}, however when I look at the console I see the result below.

*scope.theSuppliers [$promise: {…}, $resolved: false]
rowdata from within the factory:  (3) [Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: {…}, $resolved: true]*

Clearly I'm doing something wrong and in the end 'm trying to represent the data in a data grid (ag-grid) which doesn't accept the data.  I've been looking at it now for days and now going around in circles.

```
angular.module('supplierModule', ['lbServices', 'dataServices'])
    .controller('SupplierListController', 
    function ($scope, $log, dbService) {
        $scope.theSuppliers = dbService.getAllSuppliers();
        $log.log('$scope.theSuppliers', $scope.theSuppliers);
    });

angular.module('dataServices', ['lbServices'])
    .service('dbService', function ($log, Supplier) {
        var dbSvc = {};
        dbSvc.getAllSuppliers = function () {
            return Supplier.find(function (mysuppliers) {
                $log.log('rowdata from within the factory: ', mysuppliers);
            });
        };
        return dbSvc;
    });
```

BTW, I've tried instantiating the data grid from within a function that calls Supplier.find() and it works - as per below. But not ideal as I want to be able to call the service from other places in my code.

```
var rowData = Supplier.find(function (mysuppliers) {

...

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true
};
new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the promise the be resolved.

```
angular.module('supplierModule', ['lbServices', 'dataServices'])
    .controller('SupplierListController', 
    function ($scope, $log, dbService) {
        dbService.getAllSuppliers()
             .then(function(suppliers) {
                $scope.theSuppliers = suppliers;
             });
        $log.log('$scope.theSuppliers', $scope.theSuppliers);
    });
```

And you have to use promises to resolve your result from the service:

```
 .service('dbService', function ($log, Supplier) {
        var dbSvc = {};
        dbSvc.getAllSuppliers = function () {
            return new $q(function(resolve) {
                Supplier.find(function (mysuppliers) {
                  $log.log('rowdata from within the factory: ', mysuppliers);
                  resolve(mysuppliers);
                });
            })
        };
        return dbSvc;
    });
```